# How can I convert the String to boolean in the EL?

Tags: el

In `componentUnit.valid` I have Strings as "true" or "false". Now I want to convert the String to boolean to disable the commandbutton based on the content. When I try to convert it by the tradtional way `Boolean.valueOf` I think it is always false 
since the linkbutton is not getting disabled.

How can I convert the String to boolean in this case?

```
<p:commandLink  action="#{viewEventStatusController.callServiceAgent(componentUnit, chat)}"  process="@form" update="@this" 
                                                        disabled="#{Boolean.valueOf(componentUnit.valid)}" style="#{componentUnit.style}" rendered="#{componentUnit.type == 'commandLinkSelectedBox'}">
                                                         <h:graphicImage url="/images/#{componentUnit.icon}" width="25" height="25"/>
                                                         <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{viewEventStatusController.selectedEntityId}" value="#{componentUnit.selectedEntityId}"/>
                                                       </p:commandLink>
```

Comment: try `#{ componentUnit.valid eq 'true' }` but it's betterr to make `valid` of type boolean.

Comment: Yes it works thanks :)